# jQuery its Object structure?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, key, structure

How come jQuery sorts their found element(s) in "sub-categories" ([0 ... 99], etc), without declaring it as an Object key / pair?

[image: e.x 0 ... 99]

Comment: That is normal behaviour of console to prevent displaying hundreds of results at once

Comment: Yep, this is browser functionality, not jQuery functionality.

Comment: @piotrbienias Oh.. well that's strange. I'm having other results with huge objects.. must be something to do with the 'NodeList' prototype I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not jQuery, it's the browser's console behaviour for iterable objects (tested in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge).

Try to run this code to see this behaviour for an array:

```
var test = { arr: [] }, i = 0;
for(;i<200;) test.arr[i++] = 0;
console.log(test);
```

Object returned by $("div") is iterable. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators):

> An object is iterable if it defines its iteration behavior, such as
>   what values are looped over in a for..of construct. Some built-in
>   types, such as Array or Map, have a default iteration behavior, while
>   other types (such as Object) do not.

Browser is using this feature to display grouped values to avoid displaying all values at once.

To verify if an object is iterable you can run the following code in console (tested on Google Chrome):

```
console.log(typeof {}[Symbol.iterator] === 'function');
console.log(typeof [][Symbol.iterator] === 'function');
console.log(typeof $("div")[Symbol.iterator] === 'function');
```

Comment: try this... this is exactly the problem i'm facing -> var test = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
 test[i] = i;
}

console.dir(test);

Comment: *Additional to my latest comment* -> That's what I meant.. in an Object (from origin), it is not possible to have dummy key properties.. or am I wrong?